# Honor. Exception after updating system

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, huawei-mobile-services

Using Xamarin.Forms to built Android app. Phone Honor 30i. Android 10. Build version 3.1.0.140(C10E1R3P2). After updating on this build(dont remember version of previously installed build) my app throw exception in log and crash at once after launch. this is from log:

```
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: NetworkKit_GRS_GrsClient-Init_0 -- >NetworkKit_GRS_RequestController-Task_0
[AndroidRuntime] Process: ru.myApp.MyApp, PID: 24933
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
Lcom/huawei/hms/framework/common/NetworkUtil;
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.huawei.hms.framework.network.grs.g.i.a(Unknown Source:65)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.huawei.hms.framework.network.grs.g.i$b.run(Unknown Source:8)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.huawei.hms.framework.common.RunnableEnhance.run(RunnableEnhance.java:30)
[AndroidRuntime]    at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
[AndroidRuntime]    at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.huawei.hms.framework.common.NetworkUtil" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/ru.tkchel.AutoGRAPHDroidV3- 
B0zi2q4ZiBGpa_dnl0f1Bg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories= 
[/data/app/ru.myApp.MyApp-B0zi2q4ZiBGpa_dnl0f1Bg==/lib/arm64, 
/data/app/ru.myApp.MyApp-B0zi2q4ZiBGpa_dnl0f1Bg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, 
/system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
[AndroidRuntime]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:209)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 6 more
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPool11-30 
15:57:28.007 W/        (24933): Thread 0x798b1fbd50 may have been prematurely finalized
[] * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020- 
02/android/release/mono/utils/mono-threads.c:650, condition `info' not met, 
function:mono_thread_info_current, 
[HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager] Enter getHMSPackageName
[libc] Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 25015 (NetworkKit_GRS_), pid 24933 
(utoGRAPHDroidV3)
```

On Huawei p40 lite (build version 10.1.0.362(C10E1R5P1)). Android 10. works fine, without any exception. target sdk "Android R".
using nugets:

1. Huawei.Hms.Base(6.1.0.302)
2. Huawei.Hms.Hwid(6.1.0.302)
3. Huawei.Hms.NetworkGrs(5.0.3.300)
4. Huawei.Hms.Push(5.0.4.302)

Any help, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for providing the information regarding this issue, we have reported it to the R&D team. at the same time, we have provided a workaround, you can downgrade the Account SDK version to `5.0.3.302`, which should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for reply, but this is not solve the problem. im downgrade nuget "huawe.hms.hwid" to 5.0.3.302, but it generate the same exception in Log.

Comment: hi@ПавелСухарев,Just confirmed with the team that the R&D team has modified. You could first delete the dependency between `Huawei.Hms.Base(6.1.0.302)` and `Huawei.Hms.NetworkGrs(5.0.3.300)`, and then upgrade the Push version to `6.1.0.300` and the Account version to `6.1.0.302`. If the problem persists, pls send your APK to hmscore@huawei.com, let us check the info to see the problem.

Comment: i'm reinstal all nugets. Now all of them have the last version, besides "networkgrs". it has "4.0.20.301", because the higher version is not working.

Comment: did not understand what you mean by "delete dependency". what exactly i should do?

Comment: hi@ПавелСухарев, we make a small Demo, that's all included in the [Nuget Package Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3etg.png), there is no Base or NetworkGrs in it.

Comment: hi, @shirley, thank you. will try it

Comment: it help. thank you. i deleted this 2 nugets and reinstalled "push" and "account". And all works fine.

Comment: @ПавелСухарев, I am glad it helped you.If you have any queries, please feel free to contact us. :)

Answer (score 0):

“ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

"com.huawei.hms.framework.common.NetworkUtil" on path: “

This indicates that the “NetworkUtil” is missing. Since this class is part of HMS core

The solution is to try to reinstall HMS core again or upgrade if possible.